# fwrite not working

Tags: php

Is there a way to know why fwrite is not working? I mean as in .net (I am a .net guy) the method just throws the exception which can be caught and the exception message and stack trace message tells all the story why the .net method didn't work. Is there any way I can know why my fwrite is not working as I think my code is stable because it's working fine on one machine but not on the other. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: It's just returning false leading me nowhere. :(

Comment: check for the `file permission` you are writing into

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see some hints. Usually `fopen` would already fail. And typically you'll see something in the `error.log` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Also: If you rather want to have exceptions instead of error messages/warnings, then don't use the basic file system functions. Open your file like this:

```
$f = new SplFileObject("output", "w");
$f->fwrite("error");
```

That's maybe closer to what .NET has. (In practice this just leads to the same warning messages, so go for `error_reporting(E_ALL);` fist.)

Answer (score 0):

fwrite is like `int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )`

In my case, it was the `$length` of the file in fwrite was not being passed correctly, that's why it was not working.